# Name Mangling in C++

Tags: c++, extern

I was going through the article - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/

There are two example given -

```
int printf(const char *format,...);

int main()
{
    printf("GeeksforGeeks");
    return 0;
}
```

It say this wont compile because the compiler wont be able to find the mangled version of 'printf' function. However, the below give output.

```
extern "C"
{
    int printf(const char *format,...);
}

int main()
{
    printf("GeeksforGeeks");
    return 0;
}
```

This is beacuse extern "C" block prevent the name from being mangled. However, the code run and gives output. From where does it get the definition of 'printf'. I read a post which says 'stdio.h' is included by default. If this is true, below code must run. However, it give error that printf is not defined.

```
int main()
{
    printf("GeeksforGeeks");
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: See here please:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877437/undefined-reference-to-errors-when-linking-static-c-library-with-c-code/18879053?s=3|0.6947#18879053

Comment: `stdio.h is included by default` Wrong.

Comment: *"However, the code run and gives output."* Which compiler did you use?

Comment: About the compiling, eg. GCC on Ideone doesn´t like the first code: http://ideone.com/OqQg4g

Comment: @dyp i used ideone - http://ideone.com/qdJTt3

Comment: @NavedAlam That´s the second code, and as you´re saying yourself it should work (and yes, it should work). The first code is wrong (and the third too). So everything is ok?

Comment: @deviantfan, my question is from where did the compiler get the definition  of printf in second code?

Comment: From the C standard library (or perhaps a compiler intrinsic).

Comment: Please read about the difference of a compiler and linker. Both are necessary (and compiling with GCC will call the linker too unless you explicitely prevent it). The compiler doesn´t include any normal header per default, like stdio.h, but the linker has some default libs (binary format this time)

Comment: Ok, got it. So stdio or any other header file are not included by default but there are libraries which are always linked by default and libraries with printf definition is one of those.

Comment: Yes, the full (compiled) printf code is in one  of these binary libs the linker is using for your program. The compiler, running before the linker, just needs to know that there is some function printf with parameters X and return type Y which is defined elsewhere. And the reason for header files is that you can use such functions without writing such lines as `int printf(const char *format,...);` for every function.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks

Comment: @deviantfan No, calling the standard library printf() function (should) require an explicit extern "C" declaration in scope.  The declaration in the first example is that of a C++ function with a particular signature and linking with the C function in the standard library should fail.

Comment: @ewd Exactly, that´s what I said. `The first code is wrong (and the third too)`

Comment: @deviantfan I see.  I didn't realize that when you wrote "int printf(const char *format,...);" that you actually meant "extern "C" int printf(char const *format, ...);"

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler is being helpful by treating printf specially as a built-in.

Sample code "tst.cpp":

```
int printf(char const *format,...);
int foo(int a, char const *b);

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    foo(42, static_cast<char const *>("Hello, World!"));
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with Microsoft's cl compiler command "cl /c tst.cpp" we can inspect the resulting .obj and find:

```
00000000 r $SG2552
00000010 r $SG2554
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 i .drectve
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text$mn
         U ?foo@@YAHHPBD@Z
         U ?printf@@YAHPBDZZ
00e1520d a @comp.id
80000191 a @feat.00
00000000 T _main
```

Note that both foo() and printf() are mangled.

But when we compile with /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/cc1plus.exe via cygwin "g++ -c tst.cpp", we get:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U __Z3fooiPKc
         U ___main
         U __alloca
00000000 T _main
         U _printf
```

Here foo() is mangled and printf() is not, because the cygwin compiler is being helpful.  Most would consider this a compiler defect.  If the cygwin compiler is invoked with "g++ -fno-builtin -c tst.cpp" then the problem goes away and both symbols are mangled as they should be.

A more up-to-date g++ gets it right, compiling with with /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.3/cc1plus via "g++ -c tst.cpp" we get:

```
00000000 T main
         U _Z3fooiPKc
         U _Z6printfPKcz
```

Both foo() and printf() are mangled.

But if we declare printf such that cygwin g++ does not recognize it:

```
char const * printf(char const *format,...);
int foo(int a, char const *b);

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    foo(42, static_cast<char const *>("Hello, World!"));
    return 0;
}
```

Then both foo() and printf() are mangled:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U __Z3fooiPKc
         U __Z6printfPKcz
         U ___main
         U __alloca
00000000 T _main
```

Comment: So, you found that an old version of Cygwin GCC has a bug / unexpected behaviour. ...so what?  The whole comparison of different compilers doesn´t matter. OPs compiler did the right thing, but he/she wanted to know why it works that way.

Comment: Impression got that both example give output for OP.

Comment: Though, this is not directly related to the question. It helped a lot to get things cleared. Thanks.

Comment: @deviantfan: It's not a bug in the compiler, but in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the relevant standard quotes:

> #### 17.6.2.3 Linkage *[using.linkage]*
>
> 2 Whether a name from the C standard library declared with external linkage has `extern "C"` or `extern "C++"` linkage is implementation-defined. It is recommended that an implementation use `extern "C++"` linkage for this purpose.

> #### 17.6.4.3 Reserved names *[reserved.names]*
>
> 2 If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.

> #### 17.6.4.3.3 External linkage *[extern.names]*
>
> 1 Each name declared as an object with external linkage in a header is reserved to the implementation to designate that library object with external linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.
>   2 Each global function signature declared with external linkage in a header is reserved to the implementation to designate that function signature with external linkage.
>   3 Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.
>   4 Each function signature from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

What we get from this is that the compiler *may assume* that `printf` in any of the given instances always refers to the standard-library-function `printf`, and thus can have any amount of info about them baked in. And if you get the declaration wrong, or indeed simply provide your own, it is free to do whatever it wants, including but not limited to magically correcting it.
Anyway, you cannot know which language-linkage it expects.