# Getting strange error 'undefined reference to symbol 'avcodec_receive_packet'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile program but getting strange error don't know why.

`> c++ src/main.cpp.o -o test -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lswscale -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: src/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'avcodec_receive_packet@@LIBAVCODEC_57'
//usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

But When I find inspect `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57` with `nm`, I get following output

`> nm /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57 | grep avcodec_receive_packet
0000000000630590 T avcodec_receive_packet`

It's strange why `c++` couldn't detect `avcodec_receive_packet`

**Update:**
Since I'm using `C` from `C++`, `C` code is enclosed with `extern` keyword

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to" errors when linking static C library with C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877437/undefined-reference-to-errors-when-linking-static-c-library-with-c-code)

Comment: Also see the FFmpeg FAQ regarding using the API from a C++ application: http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-FFmpeg-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e

Comment: @user0042 I am not using static library but shared one.

Comment: That doesn't actually matter. The problem is that your `main.cpp` was compiled using the c++ compiler while `libavcodec` was compiled using the c compiler.